# converting long date to short date with incorrect converting

Tags: javascript

this is my long-date:

`Fri Dec 07 2018 05:47:22 GMT+0000`

but when I converted it to short date, it returns a incorrect date:

```
var date = 'Fri Dec 07 2018 05:47:22 GMT+0000';
var convertedStartDate = new Date(date);
var year    = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();
var month   = convertedStartDate.getMonth();
var day     = convertedStartDate.getDay();
console.log(year+'/'+month+'/'+day)
```

the output of my browser:

```
2018/11/5
```

[image]

my mac os date:
[image]

Comment: its return correct but month between 0 to 11 and days between 0 to 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var date = 'Fri Dec 07 2018 05:47:22 GMT+0000';
var convertedStartDate = new Date(date);
var year          = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();    // 2018
var month_index   = convertedStartDate.getMonth();       // 11  month name index
var weekday_index = convertedStartDate.getDay();         // 5   weekday index
var day_date      = convertedStartDate.getDate();        // 7

var day_names = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];

var month_names = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr",
                   "May","Jun","Jul","Aug",
                   "Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
                   
var month_name = month_names[month_index];               // Dec
var day = day_names[weekday_index];                      // Fri


console.log(day+" "+day_date+"-"+month_name+"-"+year);   // Fri 7-Dec-2018

console.log(year+"/"+(month_index+1)+"/"+day_date);      // 2018/12/7
```

```
var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth();
```

This will return a value between 0 and 11... 
The reason is that you might use this index in an array like:

```
  var month_names = ["jan","feb", .... "dec"];
  console.log(month_names[month]);   //dec
```

But if you're only interested in the numerical value, just add 1

```
  var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

As for the `getDay()` it will return a value between 0 and 6 so that you may use it like:

```
 var day     = convertedStartDate.getDay();
 var day_names = ['Sun', 'Mon',... ,'Sat'];
 console.log(day_names[day]);
```

but if you only need the numerical value (between 1 and 28/29/30/31) you will need `.getDate()` not `.getDay()`. However, no need to add one in this case.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian I edited my answer, and added about `getDay()` vs `getDate()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = 'Fri Dec 07 2018 05:47:22 GMT+0000';
var convertedStartDate = new Date(date);
var year    = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();
var month   = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1;
var day     = convertedStartDate.getDate();
console.log(year+'/'+month+'/'+day)
```

replace `getDay()` method with `getDate()` and add 1 to month because `getMonth()` will return between 0-11

See, I have added working example also hope it solves the issue.